# Why is Goliath named so?

Tags: title, goliath

I am wondering why the TV show *Goliath* is given its name.

I can see hardly any connection between this show and its Biblical reference. [Goliath on Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to The AV Club](https://tv.avclub.com/no-slingshot-required-goliath-knocks-itself-out-1798189238):

> For all the buttons it pushes, formats it breaks, and artful dissolves
>   it deploys, the story of Billy Bob Thornton as **a fallen legal star
>   battling his old firm** is bizarrely beholden to traditional TV
>   practices. Artless establishing shots of a SoCal setting that wouldn’t
>   look out of place in a CBS procedural are used as segues between
>   scenes. The first season’s inciting incident — an explosion at sea — is
>   depicted like the cold open for a mystery that’s more typically solved
>   in 44 minutes. **The antagonistic law firm, the metaphorical behemoth of
>   the show’s title,** is introduced during a company-wide seminar that
>   does as much expositional hand-holding as the scene will allow.

Comment: In both seasons, the protagonist fights gigantic organizations with his own very limited resources. An apt metaphor.